# I am using a <marquee> tag for continues moving

Tags: marquee

I am using a  tag for continues moving of image horizontally. Suppose I have a 5 images than it moving fine but after completion of last image move there is a big gap to start scrolling from 1 st image.How can i mange this?

Comment: You can use jquery plugins for that.

Comment: That tag was in such disfavor that I thought it'd been dropped from the W3C standard.  I'm surprised to see that anyone would use it.

Comment: But I not using <marquee> tag only with css and html . This links may help you **Horizontal** :  https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/qBbROay **Vertical** : https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/eYJgpVy